# How to check my access to a certain queues on sge

Tags: queue, sungridengine

I am just wondering if there is some command which tells me if I have access to a certain queue on a cluster with sge. Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use qstat's `-U` option. From the man page for qstat(1):

```
     -U user,...
          Displays status information with respect to  queues  to
          which  the specified users have access. Status informa-
          tion for jobs is displayed either for those which  exe-
          cute in one of the selected queues or which are pending
          and might get scheduled to those queues in principle.
```

You can then do

```
$ qstat -U yourusername -g c
```

to see a list of all the queues you have access to, or

```
$ qstat -U yourusername -g c -q yourqueuename
```

to determine if you can access a specific queue(the list will be empty if you do not have access).